# How to change breakpoints in prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, responsive-design, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, hamburger-menu

hi guys i was wondering if anybody knows how to change the breakpoints currently my nav burger menu for my site only shows up until 768px as seen below
[image: navbar burger menu]

i would like this to be the same all the way up until 1000px but I cannot find a way of doing this. below you will see what the nav looks like currently after 768px
[image]

instead of looking like this I would like the mobile menu to continue .

Answer (score 1):

You need to open your browser "web console" and find a place, where the width of this element is defined: an HTML tag or a line in a .css file.
You need to know how HTML tags, classes and CSS rules define the width of an element.
And then you can change it.

In .css it is something like this:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
...
}
```